# Java Transformation in Informatica BDM. Split a date range record into multiple records with one record per month

Tags: java, informatica

I have a set of date columns (in both Int and Date/Time formats) and I want to divide the date range in each record into multiple records with one record per each month:

Example of one record is as follows:

```
ID      St_Dt_Int   St_Dt_Date              End_Dt_Int  End_Dt_Date             
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0
```

I'm using Java transofmration to split the record into n (13) records for n (13) months. But I'm unable to create the two new date columns with each month value per record:

```
ID      St_Dt_Int   St_Dt_Date              End_Dt_Int  End_Dt_Date             month_number n_months   YYYY    MM  DD ext_MM   ext_DD
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   0            12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   1            12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   2            12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   3            12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   4            12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   5            12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   6            12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   7            12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   8            12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   9            12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   10           12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   11           12         1996    02  01  2           1
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   12           12         1996    02  01  2           1
```

I'm using Informatica BDM. I know that doing this using Informatica functions such as `GET_DATE_PART()` and `ADD_TO_DATE()` and etc is much easier and I did achieve it. But there is one issue that happens when my Code gets converted into Spark code during Push Down. So, I want to achieve these two monthly columns in Java transformation itself while splitting each record into n records.

My expected output is as follows with two new columns containing month values for each record as per the date range:

```
ID      St_Dt_Int   St_Dt_Date              End_Dt_Int  End_Dt_Date             month_number n_months   YYYY    MM  DD ext_MM   ext_DD  Required_St_Date    Required_End_Date
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   0            12         1996    02  01  2           1               19960201            19960229
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   1            12         1996    02  01  2           1               19960301            19960331
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   2            12         1996    02  01  2           1               19960401            19960430
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   3            12         1996    02  01  2           1               19960501            19960531
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   4            12         1996    02  01  2           1               19960601            19960630
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   5            12         1996    02  01  2           1               19960701            19960731
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   6            12         1996    02  01  2           1               19960801            19960831
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   7            12         1996    02  01  2           1               19960901            19960930
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   8            12         1996    02  01  2           1               19961001            19961031
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   9            12         1996    02  01  2           1               19961101            19961130
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   10           12         1996    02  01  2           1               19961201            19961231
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   11           12         1996    02  01  2           1               19970101            19970131
1234    19960201    1996-02-01 00:00:00.0   19970201    1997-02-01 00:00:00.0   12           12         1996    02  01  2           1               19970201            19970229
```

My current code in the Java transformation (I'm using this transformation for the first time) is as follows:

The below are my Imports :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
```

and the code in my On Input tab for creating n records is as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<=n_months; i++)

       {
        if (i == 24)
        {
        break;
        }

        o_ID = Id;
        o_St_Dt_Int = St_Dt_Int;
        o_St_Dt_Date = St_Dt_Date;
        o_End_Dt_Int = End_Dt_Int;
        o_End_Dt_Date = End_Dt_Date;
        o_n_months = n_months;

        o_month_number = i;

        Date date = new Date(St_Dt_Date);
        java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        o_YYYY = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        ext_MM = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        ext_DD = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        if (ext_MM < 10) {
            o_MM = "0"+String.valueOf(ext_MM);
        }
        else {
            o_MM = String.valueOf(ext_MM);
        }

        if (ext_DD < 10) {
            o_DD = "0"+String.valueOf(ext_DD);
        }
        else {
            o_DD = String.valueOf(ext_DD);
        }




        generateRow();

       }
```

I'm totally new to Java and I'm unable to understand how to create the two new date columns with each month value per record: Can someone please help me with this? It would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Never use the terrible `Date` and `Calendar` classes. Use only the modern *java.time* classes. The older classes became legacy as of the adoption of JSR 310.

## Parsing

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "19970201" , DateTimeFormatter. BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "1997-02-01 00:00:00.0".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

## Generating

```
String output = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter. BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;

String output = ldt.toString().replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

## Looping `YearMonth`

To determine each month on your date range, loop on `YearMonth` objects.

```
YearMonth yearMonthStart = YearMonth.from( localDateStart ) ;
…

YearMonth ym = yearMonthStart ;
while ( ! ym.isAfter( yearMonthStop ) ) {
    LocalDate ld = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;
    LocalDateTime ldt = ld.atStartOfDay() ;
    … generate your String output as shown above.
    ym = ym.plusMonths( 1 ) ; // Prepare for the next loop.
}
```

All this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

If your output is a Tab-delimited text or CSV text, use a library such as *Apache Commons CSV* to assist.